# Lanunching IMS Settings App of Samsung Mobiles Programmatically

Tags: java, android, privileges, telephonymanager, ims

I need to open IMS Settings app programmitcally using java code.
My app already has carrier privileges.
I tried the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.samsung.android.action.SECRET_CODE",
                                    Uri.parse("android_secret_code://467"));                            
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But I got this error:
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast com.samsung.android.action.SECRET_CODE

I also tried this code:

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
tel.sendDialerSpecialCode("467");
```

But nothing happens on screen, and no error is generated in logcat.

So, I need your help in doing this task.
Thanks